# Send two commands same time telegram-cli

Tags: command, telegram

I have error:

```
./telegram-cli -W -N -D --permanent-msg-ids -e "msg xxxxx "test1\nmsg xxxx test2"
```

I tested:

\n

\\n

;

|

|| or &&

Can you execute two commands at the same time?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pipe:

```
echo "msg XXX YYY"$'\n'"msg XXX ZZZ" |./telegram-cli -W -.......
```

Comment: Hello.

Error

echo "msg xxxxxxx test1"$'\n'"msg xxxxxxx test2" | /home/xxxxxx/tg/bin/telegram-cli -W -D -e ""
> msg xxxxxx test1
FAIL: 38: can not parse arg #1
> msg xxxxxx test2
FAIL: 38: can not parse arg #1
> > All done. Exit
halt


Don't Send

Thx